# Why the contract verification using truffle is failing?

Tags: truffle, testnets, hd-wallets, contract-verification, binance

I have deployed a smart contract on BSC test net and it is successfully being verified using the following code

```
truffle run verify PancakeFactory --network testnet
```

but it fails if I do it like this

```
truffle run verify BEP20Token@0x57dadB0D06483fF35C3327Bf72fd9AE66fE6826c --network testnet
```

it fails like so

Verifying BEP20Token@0x57dadB0D06483fF35C3327Bf72fd9AE66fE6826c
Could not find pancake-swap-core/build/contracts/BEP20Token.json
Failed to verify 1 contract(s): BEP20Token@0x57dadB0D06483fF35C3327Bf72fd9AE66fE6826c

what does this json file has to do with it?How to verify it using the contract address and not name?